# Guice Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to resolve address for [host1]

Tags: elasticsearch

OS centos 7

elasticsearch version 2.4

java version "1.8.0_91"

elasticsearch have 2 diffrent node sg1 and sg2

sg1 is working fine but in sthe sg2,

I install elasticsearch, and config the elastic /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

=============================

```
 cluster.name: testCluster1

 node.name: sg2

 network.host: xxx.xx.xxx.xx

 discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["sg1", "sg2"]

 discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
```

=============================

when I start service getting below error I mentioned and not started. please check and let me help.

[ERROR][bootstrap] Guice Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to resolve address for [sg1]

Likely root cause: java.net.UnknownHostException: sg1: unknown error

Answer (score 0):

This solution solved my error hopefully it also solved for future viewers.

I change this line 
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["sg1", "sg2"]  to discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["xxx.x.xx.xxx:xxxx", "xxx.x.xx.xxx:xxxx"]

I placed the ip address and port in place of sg1 and sg2
and working fine for me.

Thanks